# Electric field needed to remove an electron from a Helium atom

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electrons, atomic-physics, ionization-energy

Let us consider that we have a Helium atom. We have provided an electric field $E$, which is sufficient to pull out an electron from this atom. We can calculate this electric field as follows :

$$eE=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Ze^2}{r^2}$$

However, it is rather simple to find an expression for $r$ for Bohr atoms, with a single electron, using the quantization of angular momentum and the centripetal force relation. However, how should I find an expression for $r$ if I have some other random atom? I don't think it would be the same as the hydrogenic atoms.

Let us now modify the question slightly.

We now have the added constraint that the electric field $E$ removes the electron in the exact same time, it takes the electron to complete a single orbit. What must be the value of $E$ now ? Will this new constraint change my procedure, and if so, how ? How to incorporate this new constraint into my derivation and calculations?

Any help here, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: One can't really talk about the time to complete an orbit in an atom as such notions don't exist for these electrons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bohr model uses "electrostatic forces" that work only for single electron atoms.

Quantum theory today uses Schrodinger's equations to understand multi-electron systems.

Moreover, Bohr model is actually incorrect, and that's why electric potentials are used to solve problems, since the angular momentum rule that Bohr devised with $mvr = nh/2\pi$ isn't enough to explain why electrons that revolve around the nucleus can't still radiate EM waves as required by Maxwell's theory.

In modern day quantum theory, the electron location is probabilistic, described by a wavefunction $\psi$ which all sums down to the fact that such electrons can't radiate EM waves as electrons in an atom isn't exhibiting the same behavior as any other electron (say in circular orbits in a magnetic field).

Electron's wave like behavior plays a significant role in addition to its particle nature.

So, put simply, calculating $E$ doesn't help much in your question since the premise of your question isn't valid.